# google-api-java-client NetHttpTransport causes NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, google-api, google-api-java-client

I just started studying google-api-java-client on Android. 
Added next 3 libraries into project. (I don't use Maven.)

- google-api-client-1.4.1-beta.jar
- google-api-client-googleapis-1.4.1-beta.jar
- google-api-client-googleapis-extensions-andr

And picked sample code to work with. In the sample, it used GoogleTransport which seems not available now.

```
HttpTransport transport = GoogleTransport.create();
```

So I changed it to NetHttpTransport(), found on the web.

```
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
...
   HttpTransport transport = new NetHttpTransport();
```

But, I got exception.

```
05-24 15:54:33.310: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4586): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions
05-24 15:54:33.310: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4586):     at com.google.api.client.util.ClassInfo.<init>(ClassInfo.java:324)
05-24 15:54:33.310: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4586):     at com.google.api.client.util.ClassInfo.of(ClassInfo.java:77)
05-24 15:54:33.310: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4586):     at com.google.api.client.util.GenericData.<init>(GenericData.java:44)
05-24 15:54:33.310: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4586):     at com.google.api.client.http.HttpHeaders.<init>(HttpHeaders.java:37)
05-24 15:54:33.310: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4586):     at com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport.<init>(HttpTransport.java:82)
05-24 15:54:33.310: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4586):     at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport.<init>(NetHttpTransport.java:35)
05-24 15:54:33.310: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4586):     at net.DailyTimer.test.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:290)
```

What is wrong with this?

Comment: I'm using the example same line of code `HttpTransport transport = new NetHttpTransport();` but I'm getting a ClassCastException.  Did you run into that at all?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As you can see in the error, you have a class missing, coming from [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/). You can either download the guava lib and add it in your classpath, or use maven (or Ivy) to manage your dependencies for you.

Comment: Thank you for editing my poor question. And adding Guava fixed issue, thanks. I could not find out I need Guava. I will learn about maven later.

Comment: stupid question maybe but how do you see that com.google.common.base.Preconditions is coming from Guava ?

Comment: I've been working with Guava for quite a time now, so I recognized it, but I think that just a Google search would have yielded the same answer :)